# Why vmlinux has ELF magic number right at the beggining instead of at 56th byte?

Tags: linux, binary, kernel, elf

According to somewhere on the internet, this is an aarch64 elf header:

```
u32 code0;          /* Executable code */
u32 code1;          /* Executable code */
u64 text_offset;        /* Image load offset, little endian */
u64 image_size;     /* Effective Image size, little endian */
u64 flags;          /* kernel flags, little endian */
u64 res2    = 0;        /* reserved */
u64 res3    = 0;        /* reserved */
u64 res4    = 0;        /* reserved */
u32 magic   = 0x644d5241;   /* Magic number, little endian, "ARM\x64" */
u32 res5;           /* reserved (used for PE COFF offset) */
```

but I built an uncompressed vmlinux aarch64 using this config: https://github.com/firecracker-microvm/firecracker/blob/main/resources/microvm-kernel-arm64.config

and got this right at the beggining of my vmlinux (offset 0):

```
7F 45 4C 46  02 01 01 00
```

as you can see, the ELF magic number is right on the beggining, while it should be on `magic`

```
lz@jetson:~/linux.git$ readelf -h vmlinux
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           AArch64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0xffffff8008080000
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          9996136 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         4
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         25
  Section header string table index: 24
```

What is happening?

A code that loads the vmlinux expects the magic number to be at that place is failing:

```
    const AARCH64_MAGIC_OFFSET_HEADER: u64 =
        2 * mem::size_of::<u32>() as u64 + 6 * mem::size_of::<u64>() as u64; // This should total 56.
    const AARCH64_TEXT_OFFSET: u64 = 2 * mem::size_of::<u32>() as u64;
    let mut kernel_load_offset = AARCH64_KERNEL_LOAD_ADDR;

    /* Look for the magic number inside the elf header. */
    kernel_image
        .seek(SeekFrom::Start(AARCH64_MAGIC_OFFSET_HEADER))
        .map_err(|_| Error::SeekKernelImage)?;
    let mut magic_number: u32 = 0;
    magic_number
        .as_bytes()
        .read_from(0, kernel_image, mem::size_of::<u32>())
        .map_err(|_| Error::ReadKernelDataStruct("Failed to read magic number"))?;
    if u32::from_le(magic_number) != AARCH64_MAGIC_NUMBER {
        //this error is being returned
        return Err(Error::InvalidElfMagicNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> According to somewhere on the internet, this is an aarch64 elf header:

You are not citing your sources. They *probably* talk about some *other* ELF header.

Every valid ELF file starts with the standard ELF header (the one you printed with `readelf -h`), *beginning* with the `ELFMAG` magic `"\177ELF"` bytes, so there should be little surprise that `vmlinux` does as well.

> A code that loads the vmlinux expects

You didn't say where that code is from. That code probably expects something *other* than a valid ELF file.